# PDF print library quesion trying to use in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

this line of the sample code i cannot quite figure out.

using pdfFileWriter

```
 // the method that will print one page at a time to PrintDocument

Print.PrintPage += PrintPage;
```

this is in c# I think what is supposed to happen here is to add a method to that object. how does this translate to vb.net If there is a print example with this library in vb.net i would love to find it. 
whole example below
'''

```
using PdfFileWriter;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace TestPdfFileWriter
{
public class PrintExample
{
private PdfDocument Document;
private Font DefaultFont;
private int PageNo;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create print example
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void Test
        (
        bool Debug,
        string  FileName
        )
    {
    // Step 1: Create empty document
    // Arguments: page width: 8.5”, page height: 11”, Unit of measure: inches
    // Return value: PdfDocument main class
    Document = new PdfDocument(PaperType.Letter, false, UnitOfMeasure.Inch, FileName);

    // Debug property
    // By default it is set to false. Use it for debugging only.
    // If this flag is set, PDF objects will not be compressed, font and images will be replaced
    // by text place holder. You can view the file with a text editor but you cannot open it with PDF reader.
    Document.Debug = Debug;

    // create default font for printing
    DefaultFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f, FontStyle.Regular);

    // start page number
    PageNo = 1;

    // create PrintPdfDocument
    PdfPrintDocument Print = new PdfPrintDocument(Document);
    Print.Resolution = 300.0;
    Print.SaveAs = SaveImageAs.BWImage;

    // the method that will print one page at a time to PrintDocument
    Print.PrintPage += PrintPage;

    // set margins 
    Print.SetMargins(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // crop the page image result to reduce PDF file size
    Print.PageCropRect = new RectangleF(0.95f, 0.95f, 6.6f, 9.1f);

    // initiate the printing process (calling the PrintPage method)
    // after the document is printed, add each page an an image to PDF file.
    Print.AddPagesToPdfDocument();

    // dispose of the PrintDocument object
    Print.Dispose();

    // create the PDF file
    Document.CreateFile();

    // start default PDF reader and display the file
    Process Proc = new Process();
    Proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName);
    Proc.Start();

    // exit
    return;
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Print each page of the document to PrintDocument class
// You can use standard PrintDocument.PrintPage(...) method.
// NOTE: The graphics origin is top left and Y axis is pointing down.
// In other words this is not PdfContents printing.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
    // graphics object short cut
    Graphics G = e.Graphics;

    // Set everything to high quality
    G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    G.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    G.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    G.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    // print area within margins
    Rectangle PrintArea = e.MarginBounds;

    // draw rectangle around print area
    G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, PrintArea);

    // line height
    int LineHeight = DefaultFont.Height + 8;
    Rectangle TextRect = new Rectangle(PrintArea.X + 4, PrintArea.Y + 4, PrintArea.Width - 8, LineHeight);

    // display page bounds
    string text = string.Format("Page Bounds: Left {0}, Top {1}, Right {2}, Bottom {3}", e.PageBounds.Left, e.PageBounds.Top, e.PageBounds.Right, e.PageBounds.Bottom);
    G.DrawString(text, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, TextRect);
    TextRect.Y += LineHeight;

    // display print area
    text = string.Format("Page Margins: Left {0}, Top {1}, Right {2}, Bottom {3}", PrintArea.Left, PrintArea.Top, PrintArea.Right, PrintArea.Bottom);
    G.DrawString(text, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, TextRect);
    TextRect.Y += LineHeight;

    // print some lines
    for(int LineNo = 1; ; LineNo++)
        {
        text = string.Format("Page {0}, Line {1}", PageNo, LineNo);
        G.DrawString(text, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, TextRect);
        TextRect.Y += LineHeight;
        if(TextRect.Bottom > PrintArea.Bottom) break;
        }

    // move on to next page
    PageNo++;
    e.HasMorePages = PageNo <= 5;
    return;
    }
}
```

}

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just an event wireup - the equivalent in VB is:

```
AddHandler Print.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage
```